# How to show hindi character in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview in which i need to show data in hindi when i m binding english data its showing fine. But when biding hindi data its showing question mark sign.  But there is multiple rows so i need to show it in datagridview and there is no webbrowser column in datagridview. Code i have tried...

```
           foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtOption.Rows)
            {
                dgvOption.Rows.Add();  
                if (cmbLanguage.SelectedValue.ToString() == "hin" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtRow["OptionInHindi"].ToString()))
                    dgvOption.Rows[i].Cells["colOptionText"].Value =dtRow["OptionInHindi"].ToString()
                else
                    dgvOption.Rows[i].Cells["colOptionText"].Value = dtRow["OptionsEnglish"].ToString();

                i += 1;
            }
```

Comment: what you are saving in database? is the data stored in db is also in hindi. if so then i think no need to do anything. otherwise you need to use translator.

Comment: @raman I am saving the data in hindi and i have tried it in webbrower control its showing hindi.

Comment: Is your page using the correct unicode value?